# Fixing multi-line load with smoothdivscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm currently using smoothdivscroll in conjunction with mixed-media variable-width classes - something that it wasn't actually set up to do (it likes all classes to be fixed-width, but with added whitespace code it seems to work mostly ok.

The issue I'm having is that while the page loads the content, it's placing the divs vertically above each other, then correctly displays them when everything's loaded. See below for the example:

http://www.betweenmanandbeast.com/bmb_om

I understand that this isn't quite what the plugin is supposed to do - but it's almost working correctly (if everyone was on 100mb lines it would be fine!), I get the feeling it just needs a little extra code somewhere.

Here is a jsfiddle for the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnD3r

Also worth mentioning is that when it's a single auto-width post (such as if you click on 'Blog'), it all stays on one line as it loads, meaning it correctly calculates with one auto-width class, just not when there are multiple on the page. The code for initialization is:

```
$("#content").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true,
    autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
    hiddenOnStart: false
    });
```

Any ideas?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the problem, but Smooth Div Scroll needs to know the width of each element in a scroller to be able to set the total width of the scrollable area. It does this by iterating all elements inside the scroller, adding the width of each element to the combined width of all elements.

If you would always have fixed element widths set in your markup (specified in the CSS or even as attributes on the HTML-tags, like you can do with images), Smooth Div Scroll would have no problems calculating the total width of all the elements before the actual content of the scroller has loaded. This means I could set the total width of the scrollable area at the jQuery event $(document).ready.

But the problem is that many users don't set a width for their content and sometimes they can't specify the width because the content is dynamic or loaded via AJAX in some way, so the width of an element is not known beforehand. Therefore Smooth Div Scroll waits until the content has loaded (occurs on $(window).load) before it tries to calculate the total width of all elements inside the scrollable area.

So, that's the background regarding how Smooth Div Scroll loads content today. If there's anything in this that you think could be done more effectively or in a different manner I'd love to hear about it because the width calculation is something I get many questions about.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for personally replying on this, and for a great plugin that allowed me to do something I couldn't achieve with anything else!

To further describe the problem - when you click the first link, do you seee the multi-line load (before all content has loaded)? If not I can try and set up another example.

In terms of how the plugin calculates the width; I totally understand why it acts the way that it does, and I don't know enough JS to be able to personally suggest a solution, however there are a couple of things - for example, would it be possible to set the temp width to something like 9999, so whilst the plugin is totalling up the widths the content doesn't break the line?

I actually tried this by changing from 0 - 9999, but it didn't actually make a difference, maybe it needs something else changing to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the width of the scrollable area to any width in the CSS and then it will become overridden by an inline style attribute specifying the width when the total width of all the elements has been calculated. Something like this:

```
div.scrollableArea
{
    position: relative;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You could also try working with overflow:hidden applied to the scroller and make it just so high that only one element is visible. Then it wouldn't matter that the elements stack up vertically before all the content has loaded and their width has been calculated.

Of course, these are just suggestions - I haven't tried them myself.